# Detecting path of dragged item

Tags: cocoa

How does one detect the path of a dragged item(File or Folder)?

Can this path be grabbed when it is dropped in an area?

Comment: I want to work with the data at the path root directory.

Comment: Nevermind, i just misread the question earlier.

Answer (score 2):

See [Drag and Drop Programming Topics - Receiving Drag Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/acceptingdrags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000993-BABHHIHC) for an introduction. When files are dropped, you receive an array of files from the pasteboard. An excerpt from the examples:

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {    
    NSPasteboard *pboard;    
    NSDragOperation sourceDragMask;

    sourceDragMask = [sender draggingSourceOperationMask];    
    pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType] ) {
        NSArray *files = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
        // ...
```